# Must I "stand" in order to "stand still"?

Tags: phrase-requests, sentence-meaning

When I tell someone:

> ***Stand still!***

do they need to be standing at that moment? When I tell someone:

> ***Sit still!***

do they need to be sitting at that moment?

If yes, is there a more general statement *(edit: preferably including the word "still")* that can include both?

Edit: I probably should have given a better context to my query. I am thinking of a situation when you tell someone to ***stand/ sit still***, so you can do something:

> ***Stand/sit still*** or I will pierce you instead of your shirt with this pin!

Does the reader guess from that the position the person spoken to is in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you tell someone to stand/sit still they *do* need to be standing/sitting at that moment.

"Keep still" and "Don't move!" are commonly-used commands that include *any* position they may be in.

Comment: I had thought of "be still!", but I was concerned it might be too abstract. I hadn't thought of "keep still"!

Comment: "Be still!" means "stop moving!". I like it but it's somewhat old-fashioned.

Comment: Evidence, please (not that I disagree).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: Only that of these eyes red from reading, these ears f****d by feedback and a headpiece throng'd wi' sh*te as thought I was in E.L.L.

Answer (score -1):

No, “stand still” is an idiomatic expression which doesn’t necessarily imply the act of standing:

[stand still :](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/stand+still)

> - remain in place; hold still; remain fixed or immobile; *"Traffic stood still when the funeral procession passed”*

(The Free Dictionary)

[sit still](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sit%20still) has a more specific literal  meaning and would imply  sitting:

> to sit without moving around:
> *You can't expect young children to sit still for that long.*

(M-W)

A more generic idiomatic expression is:

***[not move a muscle](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/don%27t+move+a+muscle)***:

> To not move at all; to stay completely still. *Be quiet. Sit there and don't move a muscle.-
> When I looked down and saw the snake, I didn't move a muscle until it slithered past me.*

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: The context given by @fev is: 'When I tell someone...'. This is why I think Old Brixtonian's comment is definitely relevant and correct. Your example is about 'traffic', which, to the best of my knowledge, doesn't mean 'persons/people' but cars, trucks, etc. The verb 'stand' in 'stand still' when applied to traffic is, of course, used in a figurative sense.

Comment: @PatrickD - likewise “stand still” applied to people doesn’t imply standing. It is just a figure of speech.

Comment: I'm sorry but, to me, 'stand still' when applied to people means exactly what it means: 'stand', i.e. be on a vertical position, on one's feet, no matter how tall one is, and 'still', i.e. without moving. Besides, 'stand still' (again, when applied to people) is not a figure of speech, nor an image. Perhaps, you mistake 'stand still' for ' stay still'.